# shellcode JMP-CALL-POP technique ( Segmentation fault (core dumped) )

Tags: linux, penetration-test, shellcode

I write this shellcode for spawn a shell on the box using JMP-CALL-POP technique but i keep got this error i don't now why !!

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

my shellcode :

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

jmp short qan           

sh:

pop              esi               
xor              ebx, ebx          
mov byte         [esi + 7], al          
mov dword        [esi + 8], esi    
mov dword        [esi + 12], ebx   

lea ebx , [esi]
lea ecx , [esi + 8]
lea edx , [esi+12]

xor eax , eax 
mov bl , 11
int 0x80

qan:
call            sh            

shell: db              '/bin/sh#AAAABBBB'
```

i got this error : 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

i checked it by objdump for null bytes and did not found any :D

```
arg:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:   eb 1a                   jmp    804807c <qan>

08048062 <sh>:
 8048062:   5e                      pop    esi
 8048063:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
 8048065:   88 46 07                mov    BYTE PTR [esi+0x7],al
 8048068:   89 76 08                mov    DWORD PTR [esi+0x8],esi
 804806b:   89 5e 0c                mov    DWORD PTR [esi+0xc],ebx
 804806e:   8d 1e                   lea    ebx,[esi]
 8048070:   8d 4e 08                lea    ecx,[esi+0x8]
 8048073:   8d 56 0c                lea    edx,[esi+0xc]
 8048076:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8048078:   b3 0b                   mov    bl,0xb
 804807a:   cd 80                   int    0x80

0804807c <qan>:
 804807c:   e8 e1 ff ff ff          call   8048062 <sh>

08048081 <shell>:
 8048081:   2f                      das    
 8048082:   62 69 6e                bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]
 8048085:   2f                      das    
 8048086:   73 68                   jae    80480f0 <shell+0x6f>
 8048088:   23 41 41                and    eax,DWORD PTR [ecx+0x41]
 804808b:   41                      inc    ecx
 804808c:   41                      inc    ecx
 804808d:   42                      inc    edx
 804808e:   42                      inc    edx
 804808f:   42                      inc    edx
 8048090:   42                      inc    edx
```

then i try to test the another shellcode writen by Vivek Ramachandran , the same error :

```
global _start
section .text

_start:
    jmp short call_shellcode

shellcode:
    ; JMP - CALL - POP  =  ESI now contains message
    pop esi

    ; Zero out the EBX register (will be used for filename)
    xor ebx, ebx

    ; Move BL (0x0) into [ESI+9] (the "A" in message) to null terminate /bin/bash
    mov byte [esi+9], bl

    ; Move ESI (the location of /bin/bash) into [ESI+10] (the "BBBB" in message)
    mov dword [esi+10], esi

    ; Move EBX (0x00000000) into [ESI+10] (the "CCCC" in message)
    mov dword [esi+14], ebx

    ; Load the null-terminated "/bin/bash" string into EBX for execve's filename
    lea ebx, [esi]

    ; Load the address of /bin/bash into ECX for execve's argv
    lea ecx, [esi+10]

    ; Load the address of the null bytes into EDX for execve's envp
    lea edx, [esi+14]

    ; Zero out the EAX register
    xor eax, eax

    ; Load 11 (sys_execve) into EAX
    mov al, 0xb

    ; Call interrupt 0x80 to execute the syscall
    int 0x80

call_shellcode:
    call shellcode

    ; The CALL places this at the top of the stack
    message db "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"
```

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

my system details ( Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS x86 ) 
i just compile my asm file by :

> nasm -f elf32 -o addr.o addr.asm

then

> ld -o addr addr.o

i run it .. got :

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: This question is unanswerable without details about the target application (disassembly of vulnerability location, what protections are in use, etc.) and the crash itself (faulting IP, registers, stack trace, etc.) - even then it's a long shot.

Comment: i add more details check

Comment: You did not add the details I mentioned. The error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is useless in this case; it could be literally anything.

Comment: how i can get this details ?? im new in shellcodinng !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ookkk the code is okay the problem is solved :D by giving writing permission for the .TEXT section ...

not work :

> ld -o addr addr.o

```
> [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048060 000060 000037 00  AX 0   0 16
```

work :

> ld -N -o addr addr.o

```
 [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048060 000060 000037 00 WAX  0   0 16
```

> -N
>   --omagic Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable.

[image]